# Pandas new dataframe that has sum of columns from another

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to figure out how to do a couple of transformation with pandas. I want a new dataframe with the sum of the values from the columns in the original. I also want to be able to merge two of these 'summed' dataframes.

Example #1: Summing the columns

Before:

```
A    B    C    D
1    4    7    0
2    5    8    1
3    6    9    2
```

After:

```
A    B    C    D
6    15   24   3
```

Right now I'm getting the sums of the columns I'm interested in, storing them in a dictionary, and creating a dataframe from the dictionary. I feel like there is a better way to do this with pandas that I'm not seeing.

Example #2: merging 'summed' dataframes

Before:

```
 A    B    C    D   F
 6    15   24   3   1

 A    B    C    D   E
 1    2    3    4   2
```

After:

```
 A    B    C    D   E    F
 7    17   27   7   2    1
```

Comment: `df.sum().to_frame().T` and then to for the "merge" just append and sum: `df2.append(df3).sum().to_frame().T`

Answer (score 0):

First question:

> Summing the columns

Use `sum` then convert `Series` to `DataFrame` and `transpose`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6],
                    'C': [7, 8, 9], 'D': [0, 1, 2]})

df1 = df1.sum().to_frame().T
print(df1)

# Output:
   A   B   C  D
0  6  15  24  3
```

Second question:

> Merging 'summed' dataframes

Use `combine`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1], 'B': [2], 'C': [3], 'D': [4], 'E': [2]})

out = df1.combine(df2, sum, fill_value=0)
print(out)

# Output:
   A   B   C  D  E
0  7  17  27  7  2
```

Answer (score 0):

**First part**, use [`DataFrame.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to sum the columns then convert Series to dataframe by [`.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and finally [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
df_sum = df.sum().to_frame().T
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_sum)


   A   B   C  D
0  6  15  24  3
```

**Second part**, use [`DataFrame.add()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with parameter `fill_value`, as follows:

```
df_sum2 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_sum2)


   A   B   C  D    E    F
0  7  17  27  7  2.0  1.0
```